# Finding a textFrame in InDesign based upon its geometricBounds

Tags: javascript, numbers, adobe-indesign, extendscript

My next problem is to identify a specific textFrame in InDesign CS6 by referencing its positon on the page.  I know I can use `textFrame.geometricBounds` to get its position, but I'm having trouble getting the `if` statement to work, even though it should.

```
var textFramesArray = document.layers.item("Product Name").textFrames.everyItem().getElements();

for (var i = 0; i < textFramesArray.length; i++) {
    var corners = textFramesArray[i].geometricBounds;
    $.writeln(textFramesArray[i].geometricBounds);
    if (4.0 < corners[0] < 5.0 && -2.0 < corners[1] < -1.0) {
        $.writeln("Found textFrame " + textFramesArray[i]);
        $.writeln("Its contents are " + textFramesArray[i].contents);
        var productFrame = textFramesArray[i];
    }
}
```

The first `$.writelin` statement returns three sets of arrays, the third of which definitely falls within the bounds specified in the `if` statement.  I have a sneaking suspicion that it has something to do with the formatting of the numbers (integer vs. real vs. double, etc.), but I don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question again with more exploration.  I discovered that the `if` statement cannot understand a two-way test such as `0 < x < 1`.  Thus, I had to break it into four tests, as such:

```
var textFramesArray = document.layers.item("Product Name").textFrames.everyItem().getElements();
var corners;       
for (var i = 0; i < textFramesArray.length; i++) {
    corners = textFramesArray[i].geometricBounds;
    if (7 < corners[0] && corners[0] < 8 && 0 < corners[1] && corners[1] < 1) {
        var productFrame = textFramesArray[i];
    }
}
```

This finally works, so if anyone else wasn't aware of this limitation, now you know how you get around it.